# PowerBI Measure IF Max statement help needed

Tags: powerbi

when i enter:

```
Schedule Finish vs Today measure =
IF ( MAX ( oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish] ) <= TODAY(), 1,
IF ( MAX ( oData_Activity_Dimension[Schedule_Finish] ) <= TODAY(), 0,
0 ) )
```

the column populates with all 1's.

when i turn it around and enter

```
Schedule Finish vs Today measure = 
IF ( MAX( oData_Activity_Dimension[Schedule_Finish] ) <= TODAY(), 0, 
IF ( MAX( oData_Activity_Dimension[Actual_Finish] ) <= TODAY(), 1,
0 ) )
```

the column populates with all 0's.

what am i doing wrong? i am trying to get a custom column so that if there is a schedule finish less than todays date, it will be 0(so i can condit format this to red), and if there is an actual finish present at all it will be 1(condit format this to stay as black).

the red indicates its late. actual finish does apply.

any tips/help on how to write this?

Much appreciated,

Kevin

Comment: IF the first condition of your IF clause is true, ELSE is not even evaluated. And w/o any sample data your problem is hardly reproducable.

Comment: thanks for feedback Peter. in this case, if there is an actual finish present, the scheduled finish is overwritten. i am trying to get it so if there is a schedule finish and no actual finish, then display 0. if there is an actual finish and no schedule finish, then display 1. appreciate the help thanks